# Need guidance on best way to approach a curriculum database

Tags: c#, excel, database

I am making a curriculum map. There will be information for a plan of each term (4 terms), for each subject(about 16) throughout all the years of school (11).

A total of 704 plans, each containing a maximum of about 12000 characters.

I made this to give an example of the information in each plan:

```
[Course ID] INT NULL, 
[Course Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[Year] NCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
[Bimester] INT NOT NULL, 
[Total Hours] INT NOT NULL, 
[Topic] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[Central Idea] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[Concepts] VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
[Skills] VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
[Knowledge] VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
[Attitudes] VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
[Key Questions] VARCHAR(800) NOT NULL, 
[Key Words] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Tuning in Activities] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Summary Activities] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Action Project] VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
[Assessment Opportunities] VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL, 
[Self Assessment] VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL, 
[Week 1] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 2] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 3] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 4] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 5] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 6] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 7] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 8] VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL, 
[Week 9] VARCHAR(700) NULL, 
[Resources] VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, 
[Teacher Reflections] VARCHAR(1000) NULL, 
[Student Reflections] VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
```

Obviously it reaches the table row size limit of 8060 bytes.

I also need to be able to search for keywords in the plans. Type 'water' to see how many subjects are being taught about water.

What would be the best angle to go at this from?

Comment: What about moving some things to new sheets and link using lookup values?

Comment: lookup as in VLOOKUP in Excel? An Excel worksheet with a C# frontend? Good idea, but would it be slow to search/iterate through the keyword values to make it viewable on the frontend? I don't want the users to see the spreadsheet/database.

Comment: Don't use Excel for this. You have relational data, so use a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize your data and it should help out here and reduce your overall DB size.

Create a separate table for keywords and a join table between your Course table and the Keyword table, i.e.

```
Keyword table
[KeywordId] INT NOT NULL,
[Keyword] NVARCHAR(max_size_of_keyword)

CoureKeyword table
[CourseKeywordId] INT NOT NULL,
[CourseId] INT NOT NULL,
[KeywordId] INT NOT NULL
```

Note: this doesn't include any table identity or key information that you would want to include.
Beyond reducing the size of your courses table, you can also reuse keywords between courses.

Any columns that will potentially reuse data across multiple tables should be normalized out like this.  [Resources]?  [Key Questions]? etc...